# "Optional" substring matching with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a regular expression in PHP that will need to extract data from strings that look like:

> Naujasis Salemas, Šiaurės Dakota
>   Jungtinės Valstijos (Centras, Šiaurės Dakota)

I would like to extract:

> Naujasis Salemas
>   Centras

For the first case, I have written `[^-]*(?=,)`, which works quite well. I would like to modify the expression so that if there are parenthesis `( and )` , it should search between those parenthesis and then extract everything before the comma.

Is it possible to do something like this with just 1 expression? If so, how can I make it search within parenthesis if they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one could do it:

```
[^-(]+(?=,)
```

This is the same regex as your, but it doesn't allow a parenthesis in the matched string. It will still match on the first subject, and on the second it will match just after the opening parenthesis.

Try it here: http://ideone.com/Crhzz

Answer (score 2):

A [conditional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) might help you here:

```
$stra = 'Naujasis Salemas, Šiaurės Dakota';
$strb = 'Jungtinės Valstijos (Centras, Šiaurės Dakota)';

$regex = '
  /^                    # Anchor at start of string.
    (?(?=.*\(.+,.*\))   # Condition to check for: presence of text in parenthesis.
        .*\(([^,]+)     # If condition matches, match inside parenthesis to first comma.
      | ([^,]+)         # Else match start of string to first comma.
    )
  /x
';
preg_match($regex, $stra, $matches) and print_r($matches);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Naujasis Salemas
    [1] => 
    [2] => Naujasis Salemas
)
*/

preg_match($regex, $strb, $matches) and print_r($matches);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Jungtinės Valstijos (Centras
    [1] => Centras
)
*/
```

Note that the index in `$matches` changes slightly above, but you might be able to work around that using [named subpatterns](http://php.net/regexp.reference.subpatterns).

Comment: Nice :) (you could use the [`x` modifier](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to comment in the regex directly ;) )

Comment: Ah, thanks! I could've sworn I saw regex comments somewhere else on SO, and it was bugging me that I couldn't get it to work for mine (:

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
[^(),]+(?=,)
```

That would match any text except commas or parentheses, followed by a comma.